# Trim Cells using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have what seems like a simple problem with some data in Excel. I have a lot of data with leading spaces pasted from a web table, and I would like to get rid of the initial space. I cribbed the following code (I am completely new to VBA), but it doesn't seem to work. When I step through it in the debugger it looks like an infinite loop. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub DoTrim()
  For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    If cell.HasFormula = False Then
      cell = Trim(cell)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

EDIT:
It does look like the TRIM function is running into problems with a "space" character. This code:

```
Sub DoTrim()
Dim cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range
Set areaToTrim = Selection.Cells
For Each cell In areaToTrim
    cell.Value = "MUPPET"
Next cell
End Sub
```

Changed the value of the cells, so I guess it's a non-space whitespace! Any idea on how to get rid of those?

Comment: chr(255) appears as a space in Excel. It is often a cause of problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a non-printing character at the front of the string try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTrim()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim nAscii As Integer
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If cell.HasFormula = False Then
            str = Trim(CStr(cell))
            If Len(str) > 0 Then
                nAscii = Asc(Left(str, 1))
                If nAscii < 33 Or nAscii = 160 Then
                    If Len(str) > 1 Then
                        str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
                    Else
                        strl = ""
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            cell=str
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I still get one space character in front of the strings

Answer (score 11):

This works well for me. It uses an array so you aren't looping through each cell. Runs much faster over large worksheet sections.

```
Sub Trim_Cells_Array_Method()

Dim arrData() As Variant
Dim arrReturnData() As Variant
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

  lRows = Selection.Rows.count
  lCols = Selection.Columns.count

  ReDim arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
  ReDim arrReturnData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)

  Set rng = Selection
  arrData = rng.value

  For j = 1 To lCols
    For i = 1 To lRows
      arrReturnData(i, j) = Trim(arrData(i, j))
    Next i
  Next j

  rng.value = arrReturnData

  Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me with one change - fourth line should be:

```
cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
```

---

Edit: If it appears to be stuck in a loop, I'd add

```
Debug.Print cell.Address
```

inside your `For ... Next` loop to get a bit more info on what's happening.

I also suspect that `Trim` only strips spaces - are you sure you haven't got some other kind of non-display character in there?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to solve this without VBA. Just select this *space* and use replace (change to nothing) on that worksheet you're trying to get rid off those *spaces*.

If you really want to use VBA I believe you could select first character

```
strSpace = left(range("A1").Value,1)
```

and use replace function in VBA the same way

```
Range("A1").Value = Replace(Range("A1").Value, strSpace, "")
```

or

```
for each cell in selection.cells
 cell.value = replace(cell.value, strSpace, "")
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me perfectly as this:

Trims all selected cells. Beware of selecting full columns/rows :P.

```
Sub TrimSelected()    
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range    
Set rng = Selection   

For Each cell In rng    
cell = Trim(cell)   

Next cell    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is a result of an `On Error Resume Next` statement somewhere higher up in your code. Get rid of it now. If your code only runs with `On Error Resume Next` in effect, it needs instant and complete overhaul.

And while you are at it, place an `Option Explicit` on top of yor module. It forces you to declare all variables, a safeguard against annoying bugs that are the result of mis-typed variable names. (You can modify the VBA editor preferences to have that option set automatically the next time, which is highly recommended.)

The immediate problem with your code is that a cell is an object, and objects cannot be trimmed. You want to trim the text of the cell, so you must do so:

```
cell.Text = Trim(cell.Text)
```

Comment: This is the only macro in my personal workbook. And it's still not working with the cell.Value version.

Comment: @Greg Reynolds: My bad, this should have been `.Text`, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Its generally not a good idea to use .text because that gives you the  value as formatted by Excel (which could be ### if the user has changed the column width) rather than the actual value.
Also the default property of a Range object is .value, so Trim(Cell) works fine if Cell is a range object.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you want to do.  I just tested it on a sheet of mine; let me know if this doesn't work.  LTrim is if you only have leading spaces; the Trim function can be used as well as it takes care of leading and trailing spaces.  Replace the range of cells in the area I have as "A1:C50" and also make sure to change "Sheet1" to the name of the sheet you're working on.

```
Dim cell As Range, areaToTrim As Range
Set areaToTrim = Sheet1.Range("A1:C50")
For Each cell In areaToTrim
    cell.Value = LTrim(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me is this function:

```
Sub DoTrim()
Dim cell As Range
Dim str As String
For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    If cell.HasFormula = False Then
        str = Left(cell.Value, 1) 'space
        While str = " " Or str = Chr(160)
            cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
            str = Left(cell.Value, 1) 'space
        Wend
        str = Right(cell.Value, 1) 'space
        While str = " " Or str = Chr(160)
            cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
            str = Right(cell.Value, 1) 'space
        Wend
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```