# Count number of rows with specific text

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I have an assignment to count the number of rows which contain specific text and print the value on email.

```
Public Function First()
    Dim Source As Workbook
    Dim Var1 As Integer
    Dim Var10 As Integer
    Dim Source2 As Workbook

    Set Source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IN INPROG.xlsx")

    Var1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M1:M100"), "Orange")

    Source.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set Source2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HP\Desktop\SR INPROG.xlsx")

    Var10 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M1:M100"), "Orange")

    Source2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    eTo = "orange@aod.au"
    esubject = Format(Date, "d/mmmm/yyyy") & " " & "Weekly Open Incident Reminder"
    ebody = "Dear All," & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Orange: " & "SR: " & Var10 & " IN: " & Var1 

    Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set itm = app.createitem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With itm
        .Subject = esubject
        .To = eTo
        .body = ebody
        .display
```

My code will return all the values as "0" even though "Orange" does exist in one of the rows.

Comment: Make sure you do not have leading and trailing spaces. 
Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964769/trim-cells-using-vba-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your solution, I have found an answer for my question and I will post it here

```
Set Source = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\itsm-student\Downloads\IN INPROG.xlsx")
Set Wks = Source.Worksheets("IN INPROG")

Var1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Wks.Range("M1:M100"), "*Orange*")
```

What I need to do is basically set a variable for the worksheet that you gonna refer to and in my case it will be "IN PROG" and call the variable while declaring the range. And the codes that i posted on top are right however instead of looking the text "orange" at the source excel sheet, it find the text value on the excel file which I do my VBA on. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count any row that contains the word within a string you could modify the string in the countif function from "Orange" to `"*Orange*"`.

The * wildcard represents any number of characters. E.g. a cell with the string "Three orange balloons" will not be counted by

`CountIf(Range("M1:M100"), "Orange")` but will be by `CountIf(Range("M1:M100"), "*Orange*")`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have found an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Source = ThisWorkbook

Dim Var1 As Integer

Set Wks = Source.Worksheets("Recebimento")

Var1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Wks.Range("U:U"), "*NOK*")

If Var1 > 0 Then
 'your code

End sub
```